# How to set text inside a view without overflow in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app in react native.Am facing an issue to set sourcetext inside a view without overflow.The sourcetext font size and font family will be selected by user,based on selected value I need to render sourcetext inside the view without overflow.The height of the view is dynamic(i.e)According to screen height.Any help would be appreciated,Am really lost & dont know what to do?

Comment: Hello, I am not sure what you exactly want to achieve. Can you add some code or screens ?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={{flex: 1, fontWeight: someVar, fontSize: someOtherVar}}>
          Some text: Lorem ipsum dolor...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If I understand you right, this should solve your problem. Just read the basic documentation of the Text component and Flexbox...

Answer (score 0):

Add style={{overflow: hidden}} to the view component